# Location Tracking with Android

Tags: android, gps

I've been using really ugly and old GPS tracking in my app and decided to upgrade it.
I've came into this class & interface:
http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

but I have no idea how to implement it.

I'm trying to get the user Latitude and Longitude in one of my application tabs, this way:

```
GPSTracker myGPS = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Lat:" + myGPS.getLatitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The output is **0.0**.
Is there any way to know when the user GPS records have finally tracked?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to get location is to use the [google play location services](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary)
which are available in API8 (2.2, Froyo) and above.  With this library you can subscribe to location updates based on criteria such as distance moved, a set update frequency, and combinations.

There are more details available in the "[Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)" training topic.